# constraining chained associations without cycles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, constraints, associations

I’m trying to design some associations that don’t result in database cycles but still constrain the data in a way that won’t cause errors down the line.

**System** has many **SystemCards** which has many **Cards**.

**Deck** has many **Cards**.

All **Cards** belonging to one **Deck** should have the same **System** through **SystemCards**.

(**Deck** has one **System**—the same one as its **Cards**’ **System**, but that should be derivable without an explicit association.)

Does anyone see a good way to implement this? Particularly making it so Cards in the same Deck can’t accidentally have different Systems?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit too abstract to really help. I recommend you just try associations, start coding your app  and do amendments if needed.

Comment: It’s not really that abstract.  Here’s a more concrete example: Say you are modeling playing cards and there are two types of decks, the common one we know and another with different suits.  So you have a Deck object that defines the four suits, and many Card objects that belong to Deck and have a suit field.  I want to make sure the suit field is limited to the four suits defined in the Card’s Deck without creating a cycle (and possibly without having to create a suit model.)

Comment: It is still abstract. For example in a deck of cards there is only 4 suits : diamond, heart, spade, club and 13 cards for each suit. What kind of data do you want to put in your `Card` model ? Just "king" and "spade" or some other data that would be unique to this very card ?

Comment: Right, I’m saying what if you have lots of different types of playing card decks, so Deck A has “heart, diamond, club, spade” but Deck B has “peach, cherry, kiwi”. What I’m trying to do is make it so that if a card is associated with Deck A it can’t have “peach” as it’s suit.  And if I decide to implement suit as a model and not just as a value field on card, I’m trying to avoid a cycle where Deck has many cards, Deck has many suits, and card has one suit.  

(Thanks for trying to help)

Comment: Well if you want to avoid creating a card that has a suit from another deck, just add 4 fields in the deck model: "suit_a" "suit_b" "suit_c" and "suit_d". Then when creating a new deck, just add 4 fields where you can input the suit names. Then when you create a card, allow the user to populate a "suit" field with one of the four suits from the deck model..

Comment: Thanks, I think that would work if there weren’t a variance number of suits.  That would imply a join table to a separate model, which would be fine except it leads to that cycle issue.  Maybe I should just accept that; I guess it’s more of a book-problem in this case.